# Finite covering of a closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

Let $a<b$ be a pair of real numbers. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}^\times$, I want to construct a finite cover $(U_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ for $[a,b]$.

**Attempt:** Let $1\leq n$. For each $0\leq k\leq n$, write
$$x_k:=a+\frac{k(b-a)}{n}.$$
I would like to show that $(B(x_k,1/n))_{0\leq k\leq n}$ covers $[a,b]$. Let $a\leq y\leq b$. If $y=a$, then $y\in B(x_0,1/n)$. If $y=b$, then $y\in B(x_n,1/n)$. Assume $a<y<b$. How do I show that there exists a $0\leq k\leq n$ such that $y\in B(x_k,1/n)$?

Should prove it by contradiction? A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it must be $ B(x_k,\frac{b-a}{n})$.

Comment: Well, what would be wrong with $\{(a-1, b+1)\}$ as a single element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you could have just taken the single open set $(a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon)$, where $\epsilon>0$.

Secondly the collection of open sets you have taken would not cover $[a,b]$ if $b-a>2$, this is because $x_k-x_{k-1}=\frac{b-a}{n}>\frac2n$. Hence for $y=\frac{x_k+x_{k-1}}{2}$, $y\in[x_{k-1},x_{k}]\subseteq[a,b]$ but $y\not\in B(x_{k-1},\frac1n)$ and $y\not\in B(x_k,\frac1n)$.

It would have worked if you took the sets $B(x_k,\frac{b-a}{n})$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind helping me show $[a,b]\subset\cup_k B(x_k,\frac{b-a}{n})$? Only a hint will suffice. (Is a direct proof possible?)

Comment: $[a,b]=\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}[x_k,x_{k+1}]$. Thus for any $y\in[a,b)$, there exists $k$, such that $y\in[x_k,x_{k+1})\subseteq B(x_k,\frac{b-a}{n})$, also $b\in B(x_n,\frac{b-a}{n})$